# Invalid object name in SQL Join

Tags: sql-server

I am switching to SQL Server from the *visual editor* approach I used in MS Access. Here is my first attempt. I am joining two tables and keep getting an invalid object.  Where am I going wrong? The error message specifically says:

```
(560180 row(s) affected)
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
Invalid object name 'BillingTable'.
```

My query is:

```
SELECT [Tracking_Number]
      ,[Package_Key]
      ,[Manifest_Datetime]
      ,[Packed_Datetime]
      ,[Order_Number]
      ,[WMS_Order_Number]
      ,[Shipped_Warehouse_Name]
      ,[Carrier]
      ,[Service_Name]
      ,[Zone]
      ,[Estimated_Weight]
      ,[Estimated_Cost]
      ,[Preferred_Warehouse_Name]
      ,[WMS_Shipping_Method_Name]
  FROM [Shipping].[dim].[tbl_Package] as PackageTable

  where [Manifest_Datetime] > '1/1/2016'

  SELECT [Invoice_Date_Key]
      ,[Order_Date_Key]
      ,[Package_Key]
      ,[Billed_Weight]
      ,[Billed_Weight_Metric]
      ,[Package_Quantity]
      ,[Total_Cost_Dollars]
      ,[Tax_Cost_Dollars]
      ,[Total_Cost_Billed_Currency]
  FROM [Shipping].[fact].[tbl_Shipping_Billing] as BillingTable

  JOIN BillingTable
  on PackageTable.Package_Key = BillingTable.Package_Key
```

Comment: You cannot use  `BillingTable` as an alias because there is another table also called `BillingTable`.

Comment: Apart from that your query is syntactically incorrect, or are these two separate queries?

Comment: I want the results of the joined query to be displayed in one table.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should look like this:

```
Select PackageTable.*, BillingTable.*
From [Shipping].[dim].[tbl_Package] as PackageTable
Inner Join [Shipping].[fact].[tbl_Shipping_Billing] as BillingTable
on PackageTable.Package_Key = BillingTable.Package_Key
where PackageTable.[Manifest_Datetime] > '1/1/2016'
```

You can call out the specific fields you want from those tables instead of using the `.*`

Comment: Thanks.  Your format helped and I successfully executed the query.  I understand now how I called out BillingTable twice and thus created the error.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as the answer